# Yahoo Mail Reading Attachment File

Tags: php, email, content-type, multipart

I intend to use php to send a mail which the content type is multipart/mixed with text/plain and application/msword contents. However, when I try to use Yahoo!Mail to open the email, the doc file cannot be downloaded and gives error like this: "Network error occur while downloading. Please check your Internet connection.". Yet the file could be read and downloaded successfully if I use Thunderbird to view the mail. What are the requirements for a file to be loaded successfully on every mail viewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest making it a generic content-type `application/octet-stream`, rather than `application/msword`.  It will ensure that every application can download it normally.

Comment: Nothing changed. THe problem persist.

Comment: Guess beyond that, if I had to guess, it's an issue with the syntax you're providing.  Can you display your full content on your question in case I can pinpoint the issue?

Comment: $send=mail("user@yahoo.com.hk","Email trying","--4-11231231243-39834712349=:10867\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\nHello! Everyone.\r\n--4-11231231243-39834712349=:10867\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\nContent-Disposition: attachment; filename=this.docx\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n".$content."\r\n\r\n--4-11231231243-39834712349=:10867--",
"MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-type: multipart/mixed; boundary=4-11231231243-39834712349=:10867");